# How to submit an LSF job to exclude a specific machine?

Tags: linux

One of our LSF machines is not able to run a specific program. I want to submit a job such that it goes to any machine except for the failing one. I have read the manuals but could not make it out. Is it possible? If yes, how can I achieve it? I am using Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the select clause of the job's resource requirement.  Say alpha is the host that cannot run the job.

```
bsub -R "select[hname!='alpha']" sleep 1000
```

Comment: One can use e.g.`"-R select[hname!='alpha' && hname!='beta']"` to exclude multiple hosts.